# Add ' \ ' before " ' " of a string variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript variable which hold the value taken from somewhere else(lets say from a API call), taken string is given bellow,

```
He's the reason for this
```

I assign this string to a variable name 'sample'. But when I print it, it doesn't work since the string has " ' " character. I want to add " \ " before the " ' " character. I tried using this,

```
var sample = (get the string from a api call).replace(/'/g,"\\\'");
```

But it doesn't work?

Comment: Define "print it". While you are working within JS, having a `'` in a string should not cause you any problems.

Comment: In addition to "print it", please also define "doesn't work".

Comment: Actually the problem is, I pass this variable to another php file using GET method. I can't print it there. That's the problem

Comment: I think he means he assigned a string with `'`, but the string itself contained `'`, which gives an error if they aren't escaped. I actually had the same problem at work yesterday, and just assigned the string using `"` instead.

Comment: @Roshanck — So you are passing it over HTTP. How are you sending doing that? How are you using it within that PHP? What do you mean by print (call the PHP `print` method? Call some method that outputs a hard copy to a printer connected to the server?)?

Comment: I take the string from a API call, so how to add " before and after the string

Comment: When you say `(get the string from a api call)` do you mean `<?php print getDataFromSomewhere(); ?>` ?

Comment: @ Quentin-- in my javascript file I use 
window.location.href = "test.php?detail="+sample; to send the data.
In my test.php, I use 
$detail = $_GET["detail"]; and 
echo $detail; to print it. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Show your actual code, both your PHP code and the code produced by PHP that is sent to the browser (hint: View Source). Your usage of `(get the string from a api call)` is hiding details critical to helping you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my javascript file I use `window.location.href = "test.php?detail="+sample;` to send the data.

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape a string for inserting into a URI.

> In my test.php, I use `$detail = $_GET["detail"];` and `echo $detail;` to print it.

If you are printing it into HTML then use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)to make it safe.

If you are printing it into JavaScript then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to make it safe.

Comment: Can you please explain with more details? If you can please put the answer here using my code

Comment: How do I send it using encodeURIComponent and access it in test.php using htmlspecialchars?

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($detail)`

Comment: Thanks. It works when I use echo $detail insted of echo htmlspecialchars($detail). Anyway thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're overdoing the escape characters:

```
var sample = (get the string from a api call).replace(/'/g,"\\'");
```

Is enough, a single quote, delimited by double quotes needn't be escaped, so just escape one backslash.
A sidenote, though: if the string you're checking is a return value, the single quotes shouldn't be a problem (if they are, the api code would break before returning the string). If you *really really really* want to be *extra-super-mega-sure* and the string is long:

```
var sample = (get the string from a api call).split('\'').join('\\\'');
//or (to avoid confusion with all that escaping
var sample = (get the string from a api call).split("'").join("\\'");
```

Splitting is faster for longer strings (not short strings, as the array constructor is called, an array-object is created, looped,...)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the problem is with `(get the string from a api call)`. If you have some server-side code (PHP?) like this:

```
var sample = <?php echo $mystring ?>.replace(…);
```

…and it produces output sent to the browser like this:

```
var sample = 'my dad's car'.replace(…);
```

…then your server-side code has produced syntatically-invalid JavaScript that cannot be fixed by more JavaScript. Instead you need to fix it on the server, something like:

```
var sample = <?php echo json_encode($mystring); ?>;
```

It's impossible to help you further without your actual code details, however.